# how to create data templates in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am a JS, html beginner and trying to understand how to define/create a html representation of a data object.

Say I have a list of people (in JSON for example) where each person has the following properties: firstName, lastName, age, photo, description.

How would you normally display this list in html?

I assume that somewhere is a `div` place holder for the list which then gets populated in JS but I'm not sure how the template for the person itself is defined.

Is there a recommended way of doing this sort of thing?

If someone can show me an example that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of frameworks for templates, e.g.:

- [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/)
- [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)
- [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) (my personal
  favourite)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://handlebarsjs.com/ for a start. This will take your json and format it the way you want.

You can also use jquery Ajax method and then just loop through your results and generate HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There is also http://code.google.com/p/distal for starters. It has a syntax familiar to HTML coders.

```
<div data-qtext="obj.firstName"></div>
```